# Net::HTTP request connection too slow?

Tags: ruby, http, ovh

I've the following code that I've extract from [ovh-rest](https://github.com/Fotolia/ovh-rest) gem:

```
method = :get
@api_url = "https://api.ovh.com/1.0"
@api_key, @api_secret, @consumer_key = "123456789", "abcdef", "ghijkl"
endpoint = "/ip/123.456.678/"
url = @api_url + endpoint
uri = URI.parse(url)
body = nil
ts = Time.now.to_i.to_s
sig = "$1$" + Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{@api_secret}+#{@consumer_key}+#{method.upcase}+#{url}+#{body}+#{ts}")
request_uri = uri.path
request_uri += '?' + uri.query if uri.query
request = Net::HTTP.const_get(method.capitalize).new(request_uri)
request["X-Ovh-Application"] = @api_key
request["X-Ovh-Consumer"] = @consumer_key
request["X-Ovh-Timestamp"] = ts
request["X-Ovh-Signature"] = sig
request["Content-type"] = "application/json"
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
response = http.request(request)
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

If I do everything step by step I've the following error:

```
{
  "errorCode": "QUERY_TIME_OUT",
  "httpCode": "400 Bad Request",
  "message": "Query out of time"
}
```

But if I wait some seconds (variable duration) before doing `response = http.request(request)`, I've a successful request:

```
{
  "organisationId": "nil",
  "country": "myCountry",
  "routedTo": {
    "serviceName": "somename"
  },
  "ip": "123.456.678/32",
  "canBeTerminated": true,
  "type": "failover",
  "description": "nil"
}
```

I don't know if the problem comes from my server (ruby process to high for quick response) or if it's coming from somewhere else around..

**Important note :**

This code was working like a charm but some days ago.. Stop working.

Comment: Rather than an error with the Ruby code I'd look at the 400 error first. How stable is the connection between ovi and yourselves. Is there a cache issue on the server or in the code? Can you replicate that error in another way? Has anything else changed that may point to a 400 error.

Comment: It's question is on spot. I only have this error on my server. When I try the same code from my own computer, it's perfectly working. I didn't make any new deployment for a while and the bad switch (form working code to not working code) appeared from nowhere.. From one day to another.  How can I test how stable is the connection? What do you mean about "cache issue"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by a date resynchro. Since all servers' hours are the same, it works like a charm.